# How Read Metastock data with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, dataset

I have downloaded a `.csv` file with stock data and while trying to read it with Python it seemed to be in Metastock format, what do I need to do in order to read this with Python?

I had already found [this](http://themech.net/2008/08/reading-metastock-files/) article that shows some code to do this but it is not updated and I wasn't able to make it works. Any idea will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Metastock data directories contain both data files (`.dat` and `.mwd`) and master files. You first need to read `master`, `emaster`, and `xmaster` to see the list of mapping from symbols -> filenames. Each of the master files are slightly different, but all you need is mapping from instrument name to file number.

To read a specific `.dat` file depends on two formats: daily (7 columns) or intraday (8 columns with the additional time column).

You read these by looping row-by-row and using `filehandle.read` (specific bytes size, usually 4), and then converting the bytes into date/time/int or float.

For example:

```
columns = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'oi']
with open(filename, 'rb') as file_handle:
    _ = struct.unpack("H", file_handle.read(2))[0]
    last_rec = struct.unpack("H", file_handle.read(2))[0]
    file_handle.seek((fields - 1) * 4, os.SEEK_CUR)    
    rows = []
    for _ in range(last_rec - 1):
        row = []
        for column in columns:
            col = MScolumns.get(column)
            byte = file_handle.read(col.dataSize)
            value = col.read(byte)
            row.append(value)
        rows.append(row)
```

Each column type parsing is slightly different (the `col.read` function) but is fairly straightforward.

I have uploaded a small package to convert `metastock.DAT` files to pandas dataframes; it is available here:

https://github.com/gityoav/metastock2pd

Or, just run

```
conda install -c yoavgit metastock2pd
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for editing your answer. This is a good answer now. Do be sure to review [Stack Overflow's rules for self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). I think you're fine since you clearly answer the question, acknowledge your affiliation, and aren't spamming the site with answers promoting your repository. But it's something to be aware of.